# Do I need an internet connection to create a new laravel project?

Tags: php, html, laravel, composer-php

Any time I try to create a new laravel project using `laravel new project_name` some of the pacages do not complete downloading. I get this response:

> A connection timeout was encountered. If you intend to run Composer without connecting to the internet, run the command again prefixed with COMPOSER_DISABLE_NETWORK=1 to make Composer run in offline mode.

I want to now if an internet connection is necessary to create and use a fully functional laravel project.

Comment: the error message is fully self explaining. _If you intend to run Composer without connecting to the internet, run the command again prefixed with COMPOSER_DISABLE_NETWORK=1 to make Composer run in offline mode_

Comment: it takes an internet connection to download laravel but once it's downloaded you wouldn't need an internet connection to run it locally for development unless you explicitly plan to rely on 3rd party services (e.g. external APIs) in your project.

Comment: You don't necessarily need Internet connection if you have packages and dependencies already available on your computer. If your computer doesn't have Internet and you need a package like phpcs, you can download it from another computer, put it on a flash disk, and bring it to your computer that's not connected to the Internet. That can become really cumbersome.

Comment: Yes you need an internet connection if you haven't downloaded the packages and dependencies yet.